# Python: error message in flask is missing

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am using the flask to built a web app. I use the flaskform class to render a form. And I use the validator to catch the error. As following the tutorial on the web, everything works fine. But I meet a problem when I am doing the following thing:

1. Assume I have the following things: view function "url1","url2" and a jinja file "url1_jinja". (url1 render url1_jinja)
2. For some reason, in url1_jinja, I use the option "action" in < form action='url2'> to submit the form to the function url2.
3. After the function url2 is finished, I redirect to the current url1.
4. Then the problem occurs. When there are some illegal inputs in the form, I do not know where can I output the errors.

Is there any solution if I want to keep this working process?

### update:

I upload an example code. Please give me some advises to feedback the errors yo client side. The more solutions the better. I myself am not familiar with JS, but a simple script code is also welcomed.

```
    import flask,os
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import StringField,   SubmitField, validators
    #---------------------------------

    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    class FORM(FlaskForm):
        txt    = StringField('txt'  , validators=[ validators.length(min=4) ] )
        submit      = SubmitField('submit')


    html = '''

      <form action = '/fun' method="POST" >
       {{ form.csrf_token }}
       {{ form.txt  }}
       {{ form.submit  }}
      </form>
    '''


    @app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
    def homepage():
        form = FORM()
        return flask.render_template_string(html,form=form)


    @app.route("/fun" , methods=['GET','POST'])
    def fun():
        form = FORM()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # some functions & statements
            print(form.txt.data)
        return flask.redirect('/')

    #    Run
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: why don't you put a try/except and in case that you have illegal input you render a different form?

Comment: where do you want to display an error message, client side (with `flash()`?) or in your console (`logging` or `print`)?

Comment: I want to show error info to the client side. @PRMoureu

Comment: I am new to flask and not familiar with HTML neither. Can you explain it in more details? (Tell me the logic is OK) @Carlo1585

Comment: @hengyueli there are many way to do, I suppose the best one is have a validation on the form in the UI, otherwise you can create validation in your API and if the form is invalid return a different answer and the when the UI receive it create an error message (you can do it in JS).  Anyway if you share your code or example it will be better and easier to help u